# Jupyter Notebook autocomplete dialog in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-console

In Jupyter Notebook if you type 'p' you get this handy-dandy dialog:

[image]

Is there a way to access this or a similar feature in Jupyter Lab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the command palette and in the docs (http://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/commands.html) it states that the default keyboard shortcut is `Ctrl+Shift+C` rather than `Ctrl+Shift+P` as it is in Jupyter notebook